# Ignore Project on DevOps Pipeline

Tags: yaml, nuget, azure-pipelines

I'm having trouble ignoring a specific project in my DevOps Pipeline. I have a WPF project in the same solution as my .Net MAUI project and I have a Pipeline for the WPF Solution that works but the .Net MAUI one fails on Nuget Restore because it's Using MAUI and a macOS-12 Image.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: 'Nuget Restore'
inputs:
command: 'restore'
projects: '**/*.csproj
          !**/Portal.Desktop.csproj' # This is supposed to ignore the WPF App
feedsToUse: 'config'
nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

I get a pattern matching error though so apparently that's not right

The Error

Nuget Restore

## View raw log
Starting: Nuget Restore

## Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.210.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli

##[error]No files matched the search pattern.
Finishing: Nuget Restore

Comment: Could you please share your repository structure?

Comment: Portal.Data > Portal.WPF &
Portal.Data > Portal.MAUI.

Basically sub project Portal.Data is just a .Net 6 Library project and feeds to both Portal.WPF and Portal.MAUI

Comment: See my answer, the issue should come from your YAML definition is incorrect. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the match error via using the below YAML:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Nuget Restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '
      **/*.csproj
      !**/TestResultsTests.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '1f64a82f-77ad-4770-a098-772faae01ed1'
```

[image]

The error disappear after change my YAML to this:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Nuget Restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: |                      #Here is where I change.
      **/*.csproj
      !**/TestResultsTests.csproj
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '1f64a82f-77ad-4770-a098-772faae01ed1'
```

[image]

So the issue should comes from your YAML definition.

This is my repository structure:

[image]